# Python operator overriding: __ge__ result is not as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem about Python operator overriding: `__ge__` (corresponding to '>=') result is not as expected

```
class Book:
    title = ''
    pages = 0

    def __init__(self, title='', pages=0):
        self.title = title
        self.pages = pages

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __radd__(self, other):
        '''
        enables book1 + book2
        '''
        return self.pages + other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        '''
        less than 
        '''
        return self.pages < other

    def ___le__(self, other):
        '''
        less than or equals 
        '''
        return self.pages <= other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        equals 
        '''
        return self.pages == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        '''
        not equals
        '''
        return self.pages != other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        '''
        larger than or equals
        '''
        return self.pages >= other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        '''
        larger than
        '''
        return self.pages > other


book1 = Book('Fluency', 381.3)
book2 = Book('The Martian', 385)
book3 = Book('Ready Player One', 386)
summation = sum([book1, book2, book3])

print book1 + book2

print book1 > book2
print book1 >= book2
```

The result one console is:

```
766.3 
False 
True
```

The last statement is obviously incorrect: 381.3 > 385 and 381.3 >= 385 are obviously both false, but the last printed line is true.

Is this caused by implementation bugs inside this Book class, or by some inner bugs of Python? I am using Python 2.7.10.3

Comment: Maybe you should use `other.pages` instead of comparing a number to an object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a typo: `___le__()` should be `__le__()`.

However, that's a very unusual way to implement comparison operators. Usually you compare two objects of the same type instead of comparing a number to a `Book` object. That's why this was so confusing: the `>` operator is actually calling the `__lt__()` method, and the `>=` doesn't find a `__le__()` method. The reason the direction is reversed is that the number on the left side of of the comparison operator doesn't implement rich comparison methods, but the `Book` on the right does. That causes the [reversed comparison method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to get called.

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

I think it would be much easier to understand if the class just implemented [`__cmp__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).